# String Comparison not working in directives

Tags: angularjs

I'm not sure why the `selectedAction == 'Incomplete'` part is not working correctly. The div is not showing, but I can see that `{{selectedAction}}` in the span tags is showing 'Incomplete'.

The select is populating correctly.

There does seem to be leading and trailing whitespace around the Incomplete text when I look in the dom.  The JSON for actionTypes is just the following, so I'm not sure where the whitespace is coming from.  Not sure what if I need to trim something, or what I'm overlooking here.

```
    $scope.actionTypes = [
           { "ActionTypeID": 1, "ActionText": "Incomplete" },
           { "ActionTypeID": 2, "ActionText": "Complete" }
    ];

<select class="form-control form-small-auto" style="width:100%" data-ng-model="selectedAction">
          <option data-ng-repeat="action in actionTypes">
               {{action.ActionText}}
          </option>
</select>

<span>
     {{selectedAction}}  --- this shows 'Incomplete'
</span>

'This div is not showing
<div style="padding-top: 5px;" data-ng-show="selectedAction == 'Incomplete'">

</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0qmtkLh5/3/

Comment: care to upload jsfiddle example

Comment: `selectedAction` shows `'Incomplete'` including single quotes?

Comment: does not include the quotes.  just Incomplete with a bunch of whitespace before and after

Comment: @maxedev AngularJS will take care of white spaces when interpolating scope variables within `{{ }}`. You should post full code with a fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0qmtkLh5/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the `value` attribute from the `<option>` tag, otherwise the browser will use the content of that tag as value, and in that case the content will include white spaces and break lines (`\n`). That's why the texts don't match.

```
<option data-ng-repeat="action in actionTypes" value="{{action.ActionText}}">
  {{action.ActionText}}
</option>
```

**[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YbA9eSkd1lbFHcCreWwd?p=preview)**

Comment: @maxedev The reason for the `value` attribute must be declared was using the wrong directive `ng-repeat`. You need to use the `ng-options` directive. See @Plantface answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by using `ng-options` instead of an `ng-repeat` on `<option>`, so that AngularJs automatically manages the `<option>` values and labels:

```
<select style="width:100%" data-ng-model="selectedAction" ng-options="action.ActionText as action.ActionText for action in actionTypes">
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0qmtkLh5/7/)

---

Personally, I prefer selecting the entire object instead of the label used to represent it:

```
<select style="width:100%" data-ng-model="selectedAction" ng-options="action as action.ActionText for action in actionTypes">
...
{{selectedAction.ActionText}}
...
<div data-ng-show="selectedAction.ActionText == 'Incomplete'">
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0qmtkLh5/8/)